# My dropdown menu has added visual errors in IE10

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, internet-explorer-10, volusion

I'm using the ecommerce platform Volusion, it seems other sites that use Volusion using the dropdown menus they provide have the same problem.

I can't seem to figure out why its doing this (Im hoping it can be easily fixed with CSS tweaks):

In Firefox, and pretty much every other browser it displays fine like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjcMm.png

In IE10 it displays like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/onYoB.png

It looks like some sort of problem related to the menu being created by tables (yes I know, but its out of my control.

You can look at fullspotmarket.co.uk

Comment: You're much more likely to get a response if you actually included some code... ;/

Comment: Browser compatibility. Microsoft has never enjoyed doing things the way everyone else deems is good. With that, IE has always needed its own fixes in order to work correctly. I would contact Volusion and ask them to update their CSS for IE10 as it does not work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be caused by the inline style `visibility:visible` which is added when the hover is triggered. 
It may be better to use `display:inline-block;` instead but as I don't use Volusion, I can't confirm that.

Its not easy to help when you don't post any code as I can't be certain if this is the only cause. 
When I remove the above attribute in IE DevTools, the menu appears correctly.

Comment: It's pretty hard for me to include code, since alot of that menu is hardcoded by Volusion, and shows up as inline html on hover. (Which I can't really edit).

I can POSSIBLY overwrite their code with !important.

Comment: I'm afraid `!important` will not help you here because you would need to remove visible, the only way would be to make it `hidden`, and then you will never see it.
You could try and use jquery to remove the attribute, it would be something like `$('.class').css({'visibility':''});`